# React: How ensure completion of some Life-cycle methods before others

Tags: reactjs, react-native, lifecycle

I'm using React Native 0.43. I've one component, named `ApiComponent`. In `componentWillMount` method of this component, I'm fetching some results from an API and I want this result in my `render` method. I'm using following code (abridged version) in my component:

```
export default class ApiComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      statement: {},
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://example.com/api_url/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ statement: data }))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Text>{'Rendering API: ' + console.log(this.state.statement)}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, when I run this code I get an empty result in my console `Rendering API: {}`. As per my understanding, the `render` method executes before the results are returned from the API and therefore the state is not being updated with the results.

My question is, how I can make sure that my `render` method only executes when the code in my `componentWillMount` completes its execution?

Comment: You have a syntax error, in your fetch. Close off the quotes at the end of the url.

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it. It was just a composing error here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operation to ensure the text only renders if `this.state.statement` is true

```
return (
  { this.state.statement ? <Text>{'Rendering API: ' + console.log(this.state.statement)}</Text> : null }
)
```

Comment: I need the result of API in my `render` method. It is only being rendered once and when the `componentWillMount` method updates the state it is not rendering again.